# How can I wrap ioredis package to measure response time for each method?

Tags: node.js, redis, ioredis

I want to supply plugin to my services that will measure each call to redis and send metric with the response time.

how can I wrap ioredis to do this?

I thought to use Proxy but it's work to me only for async (promise) methods.

```
 let handler = {
    get: (target, name, receiver) => {

      const startTime = Date.now();

      return (...args) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const apiMethod = Reflect.get(target, name, receiver);
        const boundApiMethod = apiMethod.bind(target);

        boundApiMethod(...args).then((data) => {
          const duration = Date.now() - startTime;
          metric({duration});
          resolve(data)
        }, (err) => {
          rawMetering.reportError(err);
         reject(err);
        });
      });
    }
  };

  return new Proxy(redis, handler);
```

Answer (score 0):

We were facing a very similar requirement recently, what we ended up doing is creating a proxy-class around `ioredis` as follows:

```
class RedisClient {
    constructor() {
        this.initClient(); // init your ioredis here
    }

    @MeasureTime()
    async get(key) {
        return this._ioredis.get(key);
    }
   // other methods like set here
}
```

As you can see we've defined a [decorator](https://medium.com/@trekinbami/using-decorators-in-javascript-a44296e418c7) `MeasureTime` which is really just a higher order function wrapping the call and performing the measurement:

```
function MeasureTime = () => (target, _propertyKey, descriptor) => {
   
    const originalMethod = descriptor.value;
    
    descriptor.value = async function (...args) {
        const start = moment.now();
        const result = await originalMethod.apply(this, args);
        const duration = moment.now() - start;
        // do something with the duration here
        return result;
    };
    return descriptor;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response! it's a really good solution that I also think to do, but I search for something that I'll not limit the users with specific methods.